# Extract string from one column to new column – Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a column that I need to extract and separate all the genres, then add those extract genres back into dataframe. I tried to implement `str.extract()` method but don't get anywhere.

Column example:

```
|title||genres|
|-----||------|
|Cowboy Bebop||['Comedy', 'Dementia', 'Horror', 'Seinen']|
```

Ideal new column:

```
|title||genres|
|-----||------|
|Cowboy Bebop||'Comedy'|
|CowBoy Bebop||'Dementia'|
|CowBoy Bebop||'Horror'|
|CowBoy Bebop||'Seinen'|
```

Comment: look up `pandas.Series.explode` and `pandas.DataFrame.melt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = df.explode('genres').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
          title    genres
0  Cowboy Bebop    Comedy
1  Cowboy Bebop  Dementia
2  Cowboy Bebop    Horror
3  Cowboy Bebop    Seinen
```

Note that you might need to convert the values in the `genres` column to actual list, because it might just look like a list but actually be a string. If so, run this before the above:

```
import ast
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired results with .explode()

```
data = {'title' : ['Cowboy Bebop'], 'genres' : [['Comedy', 'Dementia', 'Horror', 'Seinen']]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.explode('genres')
df
```